How to remove all rows where at least one column does not have a value of 1?
I have a presence/absence matrix of species occurences, which looks like this:
                    coords.x  coords.y  1  2  3
Point 1            -69.07354 -15.76097  0 NA NA
Point 2            -69.91902 -15.86905  1  1 NA
Point 3            -69.90793 -15.79660  0  0 1
Point 4            -69.86849 -15.86500  0  0 NA
Point 5            -69.84020 -15.81637  1  0 NA

I want to extract the coords of the presence points, for the purposes of thresholding species distribution models. Taking the above snippet, it would look like this:
                    coords.x  coords.y  1  2  3
Point 2            -69.91902 -15.86905  1  1 NA
Point 3            -69.90793 -15.79660  0  0 1
Point 5            -69.84020 -15.81637  1  0 NA

Thus far I have tried the following code:
Originally I tried
SpeciesPoints <- filter(Species_Data,"1" = 0, "2" = 0,"3" = 0)

And I got the following error message:
Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

After converting to a dataframe, I tried:
filter(Species_Data,"1" == 1 , "2" == 1,"3" == 1)

But this created an empty dataframe:
[1] coords.x coords.y 1        2        3       
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

I then tried to see if the OR operator would work, as follows:
filter(Species_Data,"1" == 1 | "2" == 1|"3" == 1)

But this did not remove any rows. How do I filter so that so long as there is a single instance of value 1 in columns 1, 2, & 3 are sufficient to keep the row, those rows without a value of 1 in those columns are removed?

You can use
library(dplyr)

filter(df, if_any(!contains("coords"), ~ .x == 1))

#         coords.x  coords.y 1 2  3
#Point 2 -69.91902 -15.86905 1 1 NA
#Point 3 -69.90793 -15.79660 0 0  1
#Point 5 -69.84020 -15.81637 1 0 NA

Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(coords.x = c(-69.07354, -69.91902, -69.90793, 
-69.86849, -69.8402), coords.y = c(-15.76097, -15.86905, -15.7966, 
-15.865, -15.81637), `1` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), `2` = c(NA, 1, 0, 
0, 0), `3` = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Point 1", 
"Point 2", "Point 3", "Point 4", "Point 5"))


Using R { base}, no need to convert to a data frame.
Data.
dd<-
structure(list(coords.x = c(-69.07354, -69.91902, -69.90793, 
-69.86849, -69.8402), coords.y = c(-15.76097, -15.86905, -15.7966, 
-15.865, -15.81637), `1` = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1), `2` = c(NA, 1, 0, 
0, 0), `3` = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Point 1", 
"Point 2", "Point 3", "Point 4", "Point 5"))


Select the last three columns according to your preference.
l3 <- dd[, -(1:2)]                # Remove the first 2 columns.
l3 <- dd[, c("1", "2", "3")]      # Select by column name.
l3 <- dd[, tail(names(dd), 3)]    # By the last three names.
l3 <- dd[, (ncol(dd)-2):ncol(dd)] # Select the last three columns
l3 <- dd[, 2 + seq(3)]            # Three columns after the headers.
l3 <- cbind(dd$"1",dd$"2",dd$"3") # As a matrix.


Keeps rows with at least one 1.
# Index, TRUE if row contains at least one 1.
idx <- rowSums(l3, na.rm=TRUE) > 0
SpeciesPoints <- dd[idx, ]
SpeciesPoints  


Assuming your original matrix is
mm <- 
structure(c(-69.07354, -69.91902, -69.90793, -69.86849, -69.8402, 
-15.76097, -15.86905, -15.7966, -15.865, -15.81637, 0, 1, 0, 
0, 1, NA, 1, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(
    c("Point 1", "Point 2", "Point 3", "Point 4", "Point 5"), 
    c("coords.x", "coords.y", "1", "2", "3")))


# You can avoid conversion to a data frame.
SpeciesPoints  <- mm[rowSums(mm[, 3:5], na.rm=TRUE) > 0, ]


